# Form Validation using Dajax in Django

Tags: python, django, forms, validation, dajaxice

I am working on form validation with AJAX using Dajax in a Django project. I would like to know whether there is an efficiently way to display validation errors. For now, I return errors in the server-side when AJAX is called, and the client-side displays the errors using javascript.

```
# (if the form is not valid ...)

error_messages = []
# Display error messages.
for field in form:
    error_messages += field.errors

dajax.add_data({'msg':error_messages}, 'displayError')     
return dajax.json()
```

Is there any way to use django template tags to display errors using AJAX?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can return html that represents these errors and just insert it using javascript, something like:

**View**

```
template = 'errors.html'
data = {
    'error_messages': error_messages,
}
return render_to_response(template, data,
    context_instance = RequestContext(request))
```

**errors.html**

```
<ul>
{% for message in error_messages %}
    <li>{{ message }}</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Though I'm not a fan of this approach, I prefer separating data and presentation, and usually return only json.

Comment: It's similar, but I found it's simpler to use ```render_to_string``` and return HTML and display it in a designated div tag.

Comment: Even simpler, I customized error list class. You can see the example on https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/api/#customizing-the-error-list-format.